# Python: Is it possible to know how many iterations are in an iterator object beforehand?

Tags: python, iterator

So far if I wanted to know how many iterations there are in an iterator (in my case that's how many protein sequences in a file) I did:

```
count = 0
for stuff in iterator:
    count += 1
print count
```

However, I want to seperate the iterator into half so I need to know the total amount of iterations. Is there a way to know the amount of iterations there will be without looping through the iterator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to know how many values an iterator will produce without consuming it until the end. Note that an iterator can also be infinite, so in that case the total count is not even defined.

If you can ensure the iterator to be finite, one way to do what you ask is to convert it to list (using `list(iterator)`), then use the usual list functions (`len`, slicing) to split it in half. Of course, in this way all the items will be in memory at the same time, which may or may not be acceptable in your case.

Alternatively, you can try to use a custom iterator class which keeps track of the total number of items that are going to be produced. Whether or not this is feasible depends on exactly how said iterators are obtained.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer, Paolo, do you think that my reference to the Halting problem is pertinent?

Answer (score 5):

Since the iterator protocol defines only two methods:

```
iterator.__iter__()

iterator.next()
```

the answer is no, in general case you can't know the number of items in a finite iterator without iterating through them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `list()` to convert your iterator to a list, and use `len()` to get the size of list, for example:

```
len(list(iterator))
```

Comment: This might be expensive for larger lists. `sum(1 for x in iterator)` might be better as a general solution.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim that's a nice trick and very probably the best answer as protein databases tend to be large (NR anyone)? and trying to stuff them in mem is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem raised by Niek de Klein is linked to the "halting problem" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). 
So there cannot be any method to determine how long is an iterator for strong theoretical reasons!

I mean that I could write a Python iterator such that if such a member function exists then I've solved the halting problem.

Of course a specific container or your own custom class (as suggested by Paolo) can have such a method. But there cannot be a general one running in finite time!

Comment: I think the problem is far related with the halting problem even if it's technically true

Comment: I agree that the counting-protein problem looks more like a "how many elements are there in the container", but I wanted to point out that either the iterator is on something specific (like a list or a dict) or Niek should never wait for the release of a general purpose len(iterator) working better than a counter. 
And, using Touring's results for motivating my answer, is cute!

Answer (score 0):

Four answers are already provided and one accepted, but is your question the right one?  If you have protein sequences in a file, is an iterator the best file interface for your application?  If you need only an initial approximation for the number of sequences, it would be very inexpensive to take the length of the file over the average length of a sequence, if known a-priori.  Or if the iterator is backed by a database, the number of records would be queryable directly.

Comment: The iterator comes from a function provided by Biopython, a bioinformatics library. I do not want to make my own iterator.